# TcpClient.Connect takes too much time in .NET compact framework

Tags: .net, sockets, network-programming, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm having problem with the method .Connect of Class TcpClient.

I have a properly working TcpServer listening on port 9100 at IP 10.0.0.134.

I'm connecting by mySocket.Connect("10.0.0.134",9100)

(I tried both mySocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("10.0.0.134",9100) and only mySocket = new System.Net.Sockets || mySocket.Connect("10.0.0.134",9100))

but the software in this ROW is stuck for 12-13 seconds. After that, I can read an exception

"System.Net.Sockets.SocketException"

that is not caught by Try/Catch so I cant' see error description.

Any idea to improve velocity of connection?

Afterall, the connection is working and I can send data through TCP/IP

I'm developing a software on Windows CE 6 with Compact framework 3.5 and Visual studio 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem....It was originated by passing the IPAddress as a string to the connect method.

Replacing

mySocket.Connect("10.0.0.134",9100)

with

mySocket.Connect(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.134"),9100)

solved it straight forward.

Comment: I noticed from the error video you posted that this is in VB. Unfortunately, VB doesn't always seem to tell you when you are coding something wrong. C#, on the other hand, would not let you compile. Glad you found the problem.

Comment: btw, is there a way I can catch information from that exception in vb.net?

Comment: LOL - VB stupefies me all the time. Try creating a small, basic project in C# with just enough code to make it work. When the C# compiler tells you what is wrong and you're able to fix the problem to make it work, mimic those changes in your VB code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the socket initialization in the class constructor unless you absolutely must.

If you must, hard code the `SocketException`:

```
private bool abortListener;
private TcpListener listener;
private TextBox textBox1;

public TCP_Class() {
  abortListener = false;
  try {
    listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 8000);
  } catch (SocketException err) {
    listener = null;
    textBox1.Text = err.Message;
  }
}

public void Listen(string ipString, int port) {
  if ((listener == null) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ipString)) {
    listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(ipString), port);
  }
  listener.Start();
  while (!abortListener) {
    try {
      using (var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient()) {
        // ...
```

The rest of the code was left out, but that should get you going.

**UPDATE:**

OK, you need to get the error message to find out what is wrong.

When your project encounters an exception, it is most likely showing something like this one that I created in my project:

[image: screenshot of Exception]

That gives you a couple of things to start out with.

- First, the box in my pic shows a **DivideByZeroException** was caught, so your code should be written to handle this type of exception:

  try {
    listener = new TcpListener(strIpAddress, intPort);
  } catch (DivideByZeroException err) {
  }

No, your exception is NOT a DivideByZeroException, so you will need to edit your code to handle the type of exception that **is** caught.

- Next comes the "Handle that Exception" portion of the code: What happened? How can you, as the software programmer, prevent it? If you know enough to catch that type of exception, you can generally rewrite your code to prevent it from ever happening.

For the case of my code example in the screenshot, a simple solution would be:

```
if (denom != 0) {
  answer = num / denom;
} else {
  answer = -1;
}
```

But wait! There is more.

While you are stuck looking at a dialog box similar to the one pictured above, you can click "View Detail..." in the **Actions:** section to get the Stack Trace and any Inner Exception that may or may not exist:

[image: View Detail screenshot]

Once you have that, you should know the whole story.

If you do not know how to handle a particular exception, do a search on the exception name and the message in that exception. Obviously, someone else has already encountered that problem, or Microsoft would not have written a routine for catching it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but I still get the exception shown in the DEBUG window but not caught by this code...how shall I get info on this exception? Still slow, btw.

Comment: Moreover this looks like a server? Sorry for not specifying but I'm building a client.

Comment: I've posted an update on how to catch and view your exception. If it helps, give it a +1.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer, I really appreciate it. However, there was a problem of understanindgs because my error doesn't show the dialog..it was simply stated and printed as a line in the debug window. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6OGStt2c0D7bmxIOUZiMld5S3c/edit?usp=sharing